# Memory consumption of queues in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

Our services create queues on an ActiveMQ server. These queues exist for certain hours then they become inactive due to clients being turned off. ActiveMQ removes them by inactivity timeout of 1hr. We acquired heap dump and saw that memory consumption for the queues is as is and it grows permanently. We also added message timeout of 5 minutes for every message which we are sending. We verified this on different version of ActiveMQ even with latest, but issue is as it is. Can anybody tell us exact cause for this?

Comment: How do you know they queues were removed after 1 hour? What settings did you configure to control this behavior? How are you adding the "timeout of 5 minutes for every message"?

Comment: When I see the ActiveMQ console I came to know that all the queues were removed after an hour. I added message timeout settings and others in 'policyEntry' tag existing in 'conf/activemq.xml'.